# Will non-integrable random variables have this property?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume you have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Let $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{A}$ be sub sigma-algebra. Let $\bar{\mathcal{G}}$ be the completion of $\mathcal{G}$. Let $X$ be a random variable on $(\Omega,\bar{\mathcal{G}},\bar{P})$ **I am wondering: Does there exist a random variable $Y$ on $(\Omega,\bar{\mathcal{G}},\bar{P})$ with $X=Y, a.s.$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.?**

I am able to prove it with the additional assumption that $X$ is integrable. If I am correct, the proof in this case goes like this:

Define $Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, Y is obviously $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Let $\bar{A}\in \bar{\mathcal{G}}$, we must show that $E[Y1_\bar{A}]=E[X1_\bar{A}]$, but this follows easily because $\bar{A}=A\cup N$, for an $A\in \mathcal{G}$, and an $N$ with $\bar{P}(N)=0$.

**But what about the case when $X$ is not integrable? Then we can not take the conditional expecation?**